# array getting put in random order on production only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am doing the most simple of queries for my homepage (this is from the controller):

```
@pieces = Piece.all
```

and then on my homepage view I do:

```
@pieces.each do |piece|
piece.name
end
```

and everything works fine on my dev local machine but when I push to heroku, every time I push the button I created which does some logic on the model piece, it puts them in a new (incorrect) order. I tried doing this:

```
@pieces = Piece.all.order("id ASC")
```

to force the order but that didnt work. it just isn't pull the pieces in the correct order and each time the query is called again it puts it in another random order. what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `all`.

```
@pieces = Piece.order("id ASC")
```

Adding the `all` turns your active record relation into an array. You want to call `order` on the active record relation, not the array.

Comment: that didn't seem to do anything. i wonder why it works on dev but not prod. any other suggestions?

Comment: Try doing `@pieces = Piece.order("id DESC")` and see if the results are the same. If they are then I don't know what's wrong. But if the order is reversed then it **is** being ordered.

Comment: yea that's not working either, but at least i'm heading in the right direction now. thanks